# Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using `EF 6.1` and I enabled code first migration in my project by

```
Enable-Migrations
Add-Migration InitializeDb -ConnectionProviderName System.Data.SqlClient -ConnectionString "Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=myDb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;password=******;application name = L4"
Update-Database  -ConnectionProviderName System.Data.SqlClient -ConnectionString "Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=myDb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;password=******;application name = L4" -verbose -script
```

When I specify my `ConnectionString`, `ConnectionProviderName`  explicitly with `Add-Migration` and `Update-database` in package manager console
it work correctly:

```
Add-migration updateXtable -ConnectionProviderName System.Data.SqlClient -ConnectionString "Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=myDb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;password=******;application name = L4"
```

but when I use `Add-Migration`without extra informations:

```
add-migration updateXtable
```

I get following error:

> Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [201408300955376_InitializeDb, 201408311028404_Test]. Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration.

So, I have to use following command each time I need update my Database:

```
Add-Migration UpdateXTable -ConnectionProviderName System.Data.SqlClient -ConnectionString "Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=myDb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;password=******;application name = L4"
Update-Database  -ConnectionProviderName System.Data.SqlClient -ConnectionString "Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=myDb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;password=******;application name = L4" -verbose -script
```

It's my project(that contains my `DbContext`) `app.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
 <entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory,  EntityFramework" />
 <providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
 </providers>
 </entityFramework>
 <connectionStrings>
 <add name="ERPContext" connectionString="Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=myDb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;password=******;application name = L4" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>

 <startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
 </startup>   
</configuration>
```

Does anyone know where is the problem?

Comment: Could you provide more detail command that you executed in sequence?  something like, Edit the model -> `Enable-Migrations` -> `Add-Migration updateXtable -ConnectionProviderName ..` -> `Update-Database -ConnectionProviderName ..` -> Edit model again -> `Add-Migration` ?

Comment: Make sure that default project in PackageManagerConsole and the startup project in the solution is the project that contains `DbContext`

Comment: @YuliamChandra: both are set to the project that contains `DbContext`.

Comment: Is the `ContextKey` property of the `Configuration` properly set to the key in the `__MigrationHistory` table ?

Comment: @YuliamChandra: do you mean `ContextKey` in `Configuration.cs`? if yeah, there isn't any `ContextKey`.

Comment: Yes, you need to set it to value that matches the `ContextKey` of `__MigrationHistory`, probably you run the `Enable-Migrations` command with connection string parameter too

Comment: @YuliamChandra: how can I set `ContextKey` of `__MigrationHistory`?

Comment: just set it in the `Configuration` constructor to `ContextKey = "[Namespace.[InnerNamespace.].]DbContextClassName";`

Comment: @YuliamChandra: I set it, but nothing changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60520/discussion-between-yuliam-chandra-and-masoud).

Comment: I was following a along with a course and ran into this issue, and although the project was set as the default project in the package manager console, it wasn't until I set my DAL project as the startup project that it actually started to work for anything other than the first migration,

Comment: gods dangit! setting the startup project as my model project was the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the problem! 
As [Mohamad Bataineh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2551849/mohamad-bataineh) said in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949802/target-database-is-not-changing-when-doing-update-database-in-asp-net-mvc) (see the answers)

> In your DbContext class, you have need to specify the base class constructer with the proper name to your sql source. For example name=MyDBEntities

In the other word I changed my existing dbcontext's constructor

```
public MyDbContext()
{
}
```

To

```
public MyDbContext(): base("name=ERPContext")
{
}
```

Answer (score 22):

To resolve this issue, I changed my default project to the one with the `app.config` containing the proper connection string.

This should have been obvious, since the system was detecting **none** of the migrations as applied - an obvious sign that it was not finding the DB, an obvious reason for that being that it could not find the connection string (as OP concluded).

"Hindsight is 20/20".

Comment: My startup project contains proper connection string, but I have mentioned problem.

Comment: I am working in a Azure Cloud Service project so the Azure project needs to be set as the startup project. Going by your recommendation I added the connection string to the app.config in the Data project so EF can access the connection string. Alternatively -StartUpProjectName "Web" can be provided in the command where Web is the project with the connection string

Comment: @JohnMc that is not my suggestion. My suggestion is to set your project with the connection string as the startup project, run your commands in NuGet Packet Manager Console, then set the startup project to be whatever project is supposed to run.

Comment: I know what your suggestion was, ultimately to allow Nuget to recognise the correct connection string to use by temporarily changing the start up project. Both of my suggested answers are easier and quicker but based on the same root cause

Comment: Add a new answer. :) ("-StartupProject Foo" is more practical; but I don't think they are easier.)

Comment: It also can a proper project, but any error in the web.config's ConnectionString; for example, a user with no permissions to access the DB.

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting this error. In addition to correctly setting the Default Project (as mentioned by ANeves), I also had to set the project with the connection string as the StartUp Project in Solution Explorer. Only once I correctly set both of these did the error go away.

Comment: If I could upvote this 1000000 times I would. Just lost 45 minutes.... All I had to do was set the startup project :/

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get rid of the message by deleting the corresponding migration in my Migrations folder(in the Solutions Explorer), then add the new migration and finally updating the database.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete that migration from migration folder which showing error and not updating database. Then again add migration. It will work.

Answer (score -2):

Just delete the migration that you have Error
it worked for me